# libtiff x64 visual studio 2017 : Linker Issue

Tags: c++, visual-studio, 64-bit, linker-errors, libtiff

I tried to use nuget package for libtiff : [=> Package <=](https://www.nuget.org/packages/libtiff-msvc-x64/)

I wrote a little piece of code in order to read a multiframe image tif file.

```
vector<Mat> LibTiffReader::ReadMultiframeTiff(std::string FilePath)
{
    vector<Mat> Result;
    TIFF* tif = TIFFOpen(FilePath.c_str(), "r");
    if (tif)
    {
        //Si le tif est ouvert, on itère sur ce qu'il y'a dedans...
        do
        {
            Mat Image;
            unsigned int width, height;
            uint32* raster;

            // On récupère la taille du tiff..
            TIFFGetField(tif, TIFFTAG_IMAGEWIDTH, &width);
            TIFFGetField(tif, TIFFTAG_IMAGELENGTH, &height);

            uint npixels = width*height; // get the total number of pixels

            raster = (uint32*)_TIFFmalloc(npixels * sizeof(uint32)); // allocate temp memory (must use the tiff library malloc)
            if (raster == NULL) // check the raster's memory was allocaed
            {
                TIFFClose(tif);
                cerr << "Could not allocate memory for raster of TIFF image" << endl;
                return vector<Mat>();
            }

            if (!TIFFReadRGBAImage(tif, width, height, raster, 0))
            {
                TIFFClose(tif);
                cerr << "Could not read raster of TIFF image" << endl;
                return vector<Mat>();
            }
            Image = Mat(width, height, CV_8UC3); // create a new matrix of w x h with 8 bits per channel and 3 channels (RGBA)

                                                 // itterate through all the pixels of the tif
            for (uint x = 0; x < width; x++)
                for (uint y = 0; y < height; y++)
                {
                    uint32& TiffPixel = raster[y*width + x]; // read the current pixel of the TIF
                    Vec3b& pixel = Image.at<Vec3b>(Point(y, x)); // read the current pixel of the matrix
                    pixel[0] = TIFFGetB(TiffPixel); // Set the pixel values as BGR
                    pixel[1] = TIFFGetG(TiffPixel);
                    pixel[2] = TIFFGetR(TiffPixel);
                }
            _TIFFfree(raster);
            Result.push_back(Image);
        } while (TIFFReadDirectory(tif));
    }

    return Result;
}
```

I need to use libtiff, because i need to do some stuff with exif data of my image what OpenCV don't allow me to do.

The problem is that when i want to compile, i have linker errors :

```
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol inflateInit_ SIA <Path>\tiff.lib(tif_zip.obj)    1   
Error   LNK2001 LNK2001 unresolved external symbol inflateInit_ SIA <Path>\tiff.lib(tif_pixarlog.obj)   1
```

My package.config file is like that :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="libtiff-msvc-x64" version="4.0.7.8808" targetFramework="native" />
</packages>
```

When i go on my project properties, i don't see any packages parameters.
I tried to add manualy linker options to .lib files, but i have the same issues.

Comment: `inflateInit` looks like a symbol from zlib. also it would be a good idea to build libtiff manually instead of using that package

Comment: linker issues can be related to obviously linker settings, but also difference in what you're trying to compile versus the library you're linking ie your project is 64bit build but library you're linking to is 32bit, or dynamic versus static library. So it's important to check these. Sometimes I find using absolute paths in the settings also helps troubleshoot these issues.

Comment: What is sure is that i used the x64 package and my software is x64 too.
Just i don't know how is managed the configuration of packages.
Do you know where i can check paths ?

Answer (score 3):

Exactly like said @ReturnVoid, the library downloaded with the nuget package was not compiled correctly for my system.

To solve the problem :

- Go on [libtiff index](http://download.osgeo.org/libtiff/) and download the last version.
- Go in the download directory and use cmake to generate it with following command :

  cmake -G "Visual Studio 15 2017 Win64"
- Once it is done, open the project with Visual studio 2017
- Build both Debug and Release library (you can find it then in libtiff subdirectory).
- Add \libtiff as include directory. Add \libtiff\Release as Linker's
  directory Add tiff.lib as Linked library Add a prebuild query to copy
  tiff.dll and tiffxx.dll to output directory.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="libjpeg" version="9.0.1.4" targetFramework="native" />
  <package id="libjpeg.redist" version="9.0.1.4" targetFramework="native" />
  <package id="libtiff" version="4.0.6.2" targetFramework="native" />
  <package id="libtiff.redist" version="4.0.6.2" targetFramework="native" />
  <package id="libtiff-msvc14-x64" version="4.0.7.7799" targetFramework="native" />
  <package id="zlib" version="1.2.8.8" targetFramework="native" />
  <package id="zlib.v120.windesktop.msvcstl.dyn.rt-dyn" version="1.2.8.8" targetFramework="native" />
  <package id="zlib.v140.windesktop.msvcstl.dyn.rt-dyn" version="1.2.8.8" targetFramework="native" />
</packages>
```

Maybe dependency problems. My nuget packages config is above.