# How to create CMYK mode image in c++?

Tags: visual-studio, opencv, cmyk, libtiff

I am working on opencv recently. And I need to create image mat and write it to .tif image file. The .tif file should be CMYK mode when it is opened in photoshop for printing.

But when I tried to `imread` CMYK image file with `UNCHANGED` type, and then `imwrite` the mat to  .tif file, it’s still RGB mode in photoshop.

Is the image only saved as RGB(or BGR) mode by opencv?
(I found some answers that python have library which can choose the CMYK mode to save. But I want to know is there any way to solve this in C++?)

---

Thanks @Mark.
I meet some troubles when I am trying to compile libtiff library in windows10.

I download [libtiff](https://download.osgeo.org/libtiff) with version tiff-4.0.10.zip. And use `nmake /f makefile.vc` to compile in vs2017. (without any change in nmake.opt).

Then get some .dll .lib file. Link the libtiff_i.lib to library folder and hearder files to include folder in project.

Try @Mark code for testing. Then, I meet error(LNK2019) in vs which looks like link problem.

```
LNK2019 unresolved external symbol TIFFClose referenced in function "bool __cdecl tiffwrite(char const *,class cv::Mat)" (?tiffwrite@@YA_NPEBDVMat@cv@@@Z)  
LNK2019 unresolved external symbol TIFFSetField referenced in function "bool __cdecl tiffwrite(char const *,class cv::Mat)" (?tiffwrite@@YA_NPEBDVMat@cv@@@Z)       
LNK2019 unresolved external symbol TIFFWriteScanline referenced in function "bool __cdecl tiffwrite(char const *,class cv::Mat)" (?tiffwrite@@YA_NPEBDVMat@cv@@@Z)  
LNK2019 unresolved external symbol TIFFOpen referenced in function "bool __cdecl tiffwrite(char const *,class cv::Mat)" (?tiffwrite@@YA_NPEBDVMat@cv@@@Z)
```

I am not sure is it the link problem or compiled file (libtiff.dll,libtiff_i.lib) problem?

(Here are link setting in vs2017 :[linker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cyTD4.png)
[lib and include](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gGA2U.png)

---

I fix this problem by using **cmake** to compile `libtiff`.

Follow this [Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54315899/12291141) can get the right library for vs2017 on windows(64-bit).

Comment: "Primary OpenCV modes are BGR/gray. BGRA is optional. Other modes are not supported in general." - commented alalek, one of the OpenCV maintainers, under a [similar GitHub issue](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/10132#issuecomment-346284835).

Comment: @HansHirse Thanks for your answer. I am trying to figure out this problem in other way.

Comment: Ok, it looks like the compilation worked, so your `include` directories are presumably correct, so yes, I agree it looks like a linker problem. I shall dig around and see what I can see. Maybe add `tiff` and `visual-studio` tags to your question to attract the right people.

Comment: Do you know why it is `libtiff-i.lib`, specifically the `-i` part? Maybe include a directory  listing of the files produced by the `nmake` command...

Comment: Actually I don't know why it is `libtiff-i.lib`. I visit some questions and someone says the difference between `libtiff-i.lib` and `libtiff.lib` is static library or not. But both library are enough for use `libtiff`.
I am wondering maybe I should change some settings in `nmake.opt` before I compile it.

Answer (score 2):

I think the proper answer is to code it up using `libtiff`. I am no expert on `libtiff` but this seems to work for the cases I have tried:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

extern "C" {
#define uint64 uint64_hack_
#define int64 int64_hack_
#include "tiffio.h"
#undef uint64
#undef uint64
}

using namespace cv;

bool tiffwrite(const char* name, Mat image){

   TIFF* tif = TIFFOpen(name, "w");
   if(tif==NULL){
      std::cerr << "ERROR: Unable to open output file";
      return false;
   }

   int width  = image.cols;
   int height = image.rows;

   // We expect 4 channels
   int channels = image.channels();
   assert(channels==4);

   // We expect 8-bit data
   int bytespersample = image.elemSize1();
   assert(bytespersample == 1);

   TIFFSetField(tif, TIFFTAG_IMAGELENGTH, height);
   TIFFSetField(tif, TIFFTAG_IMAGEWIDTH, width);
   TIFFSetField(tif, TIFFTAG_PLANARCONFIG, PLANARCONFIG_CONTIG);
   TIFFSetField(tif, TIFFTAG_SAMPLESPERPIXEL, channels);
   TIFFSetField(tif, TIFFTAG_COMPRESSION, COMPRESSION_LZW);
   TIFFSetField(tif, TIFFTAG_BITSPERSAMPLE, 8*bytespersample);
   TIFFSetField(tif, TIFFTAG_ROWSPERSTRIP, 8);
   TIFFSetField(tif, TIFFTAG_PHOTOMETRIC, PHOTOMETRIC_SEPARATED);

   // Write to file, 1 scanline at a time
   for (int row = 0; row < height; row++) {
      // std::cerr << "DEBUG: Writing row " << row << std::endl;

      // Get pointer to row
      cv::Vec4b* ptr = image.ptr<cv::Vec4b>(row);

      int ret = TIFFWriteScanline(tif, (unsigned char*)ptr, row, 0);
      if (ret == -1) {
         TIFFClose(tif);
         return false;
      }
   }
   TIFFClose(tif);
   return true;
}

int
main(int argc,char*argv[])
{
    // Create a 4-channel CMYK yellow image
    Mat4b image(480, 640, Vec4b(0,0,255,0));

    // Write as CMYK TIFF
    tiffwrite("result.tif",image);
}
```

---

I have also come up with a couple of hacks you may feel like trying.

First and simplest hack, save with **OpenCV** as usual as a JPEG, TIFF or PNG, then use `system()` function to shell out to **ImageMagick** and convert to a CMYK TIFF from there.

```
cv2::imwrite("intermediate.jpg",image);

system("...");
```

And inside there you put the equivalent of:

```
convert intermediate.jpg -colorspace CMYK result.tif
```

Or if using v7 of **ImageMagick**

```
magick intermediate.jpg -colorspace CMYK result.tif
```

---

Second hack, if you don't want to install and depend on **ImageMagick**... there is a tool called [raw2tiff](http://www.libtiff.org/man/raw2tiff.1.html) that ships with `libtiff`. You can pass it a raw file (no headers) and it will convert it to a TIFF for you. So you would basically use OpenCV to write the raw C bytes, then the raw M bytes, then the raw Y bytes and the raw K bytes into a single file and use `system()` to call that utility. I used this command line:

```
raw2tiff -w 1024 -l 768 -b 4 -i band -c lzw -p cmyk CMYK result.tif
```

So my image was 1024 pixels wide, 768 pixels tall, consisting of 4 bands in file `CMYK` and I wanted an LZW-compressed TIFF called `result.tif`. That opens to look like this in Photoshop:

[image]

I made synthetic C, M, Y and K channels with **ImageMagick** like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Make raw and viewable C channel
convert -size 1024x768 gradient: -depth 8 -write gray:C C.png
# Make raw and viewable M channel
convert -size 1024x768 xc:black  -depth 8 -write gray:M M.png
# Make raw and viewable Y channel
convert -size 768x1024 gradient: -rotate 90 -depth 8 -write gray:Y Y.png
# Make raw and viewable K channel
convert -colorspace RGB -size 400x400 gradient: -gravity center -background black -extent 1024x768 -depth 8 -write gray:K K.png

# Stack side-by-side, just for viewing
convert C.png M.png Y.png K.png  +append CMYK.png

# Concatenate them all together into single file "CMYK" as input file for "raw2tiff"
cat C M Y K > CMYK
```

Here are the 4 images, appended side-by-side with C on the left, then M, then Y and finally with K on the right.

[image]

In your case, you would get the `data` pointer to your `Mat` and simply write height*width bytes for each channel to a binary file, rather than use **ImageMagick**. You can see how to do that in the `libtiff` example at the top of my answer.

**Keywords**: TIFF, TIF, image processing, libtiff, CMYK, colour separation, color separation, Photoshop.

Looking at the image, I guess I should have negated (inverted) the image first, but that is not too hard.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. But I meet some troubles when I am trying to compile `libtiff`. I download `libtiff` from http://download.osgeo.org/libtiff/ with version tiff-4.0.10.zip. And I use `nmake /f makefile.vc` to compile in vs2017. Link the libtiff.dll,libtiff_i.lib to library and tif_config.h, tif_dir.h, tiff.h, tiffconf.h, tiffio.h, tiffiop.h, tiffvers.h, uvcode.h to include in project. Try your code in answer for testing. Then, I meet some error(LNK2019) which looks like link problem. I am not sure is it the link problem or compiled file(libtiff.dll,libtiff_i.lib) problem?

Comment: I'm really sorry but I don't use Windows or VS2017. Maybe if you screen-grab your VS compiler and linker settings pages and edit it into your question along with the exact error message, I or someone else, may spot something. Don't put it in a comment please (too hard to read) - click `edit` under your question. Thanks.